# python xml.dom - access keys that are child of another key

Tags: python, xml, minidom

I am trying to access data from a xml file made as following

```
<datafile>
    <header>
        <name>catalogue</name>
        <description>the description</description>
    </header>
    <item name="jack">
        <description>the headhunter</description>
        <year>1981</year>
    </item>
    <item name="joe">
        <description>the butler</description>
        <year>1995</year>
    </item>
    <item name="david">
        <description>guest</description>
        <year>2000</year>
    </item>
</datafile>
```

I would like to parse all the `name` tags, and when that match, I would like to retrieve the description.
So far I can retrieve all the `item`, and I can print out the name field, but I can't find a way to access the sub-tag `description` and `year`.

```
from xml.dom import minidom

xmldoc = minidom.parse("myfile.xml")
# This does retrieve all the item elements 
itemlist = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('item')
print(len(itemlist))
# This does print the name of the first element
print(itemlist[0].attributes['name'].value)
# This give me a key error, although I can see that the child element 1 of itemlist is the description
print(itemlist[1].attributes['description'].value)
```

I am not sure how to access the sub-elements, since they are children of the item element; do I need to create another itemlist from the item element list to retrieve the description key and access its value? Or am I totally off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to extract the data. Not sure it's the most elegant one, but it works:

```
for item in xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("item"):
    name = item.attributes.getNamedItem("name").value
    print(f"name is {name}") 
    desc = item.getElementsByTagName("description")[0].childNodes[0].data
    print(f"description is {desc}")
```

The output is:

```
name is jack
description is the headhunter
name is joe
description is the butler
name is david
description is guest
```

Note that the documentation of minidom is, well, kind of lacking. But, it (mostly) implements the DOM standard - see [documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element).

Comment: Thanks! I was missing the `childNodes` part; works like a charm

Comment: Great. Could you please accept it as an answer for future generations?

Answer (score 1):

One line - using [ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''
<datafile>
    <header>
        <name>catalogue</name>
        <description>the description</description>
    </header>
    <item name="jack">
        <description>the headhunter</description>
        <year>1981</year>
    </item>
    <item name="joe">
        <description>the butler</description>
        <year>1995</year>
    </item>
    <item name="david">
        <description>guest</description>
        <year>2000</year>
    </item>
</datafile>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
data = [(i.attrib['name'],i.find('./description').text) for i in root.findall('.//item')]
print(data)
```

output

```
[('jack', 'the headhunter'), ('joe', 'the butler'), ('david', 'guest')]
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative solution! Nice usage of list comprehension BTW. So you use the text attribute of the element, via find, to get the value. I am amazed how the same XML module has such different ways to parse a file; no surprise many prefer to use JSON, which is much more straightforward :) Thanks!